# Border with lighter color appears when image is resized

Tags: adobe-photoshop, generate-image-assets

I'm using the [asset generation](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html#generate-image-assets-from-layers) feature of Photoshop to create an icon with different sizes using one smart object.

The problem appears in the small icons. For some reason, a border with a lighter color appears around the icons, and the smaller the icon the clearer the border.

[image]

[image]

I guess this artifact is caused by the downsampling, but is there any way to eliminate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/shrinking-down-a-smart-object-causes-drastic-sharpening).

There is no direct way to control the resampling method used for smart objects. But one can change the default resampling method from preferences:

[image]

Here is the result after changing the method from "Bicubic Automatic" to "Bilinear":

[image]

Comment: Thisdoes not reallynsolve the problem it mitigates it.

Comment: True, but I don't imagine there will be a better result though.

Comment: well you could use something like imagemagic instead and use blackman-harris, lanczos etc. And or atleast adjust the window of the reconstruction filter. In a ideal world Adobe would follow the times (or atleast last 50 years of signal processing advancements) but apparently not interested. Anyway you can do this yourself in photoshop if you wish.

Comment: Interesting! If I had more time I'd love to experiment with those algorithms. But how can that be done in Photoshop? By implementing those algorithms in Photoshop Scripting?

Comment: Hejazi, well photoshop has the convolve function just upscale, cnovolve an downsale with nearest neighbour. Or just export one picture then let imagemagic resample it.

Answer (score 0):

That is more likely caused by sharpening.

Do not "eliminate" it. What you should do is avoid it in the first place.

Use a simpler resizing method. And then, if you see that you want some sharpening apply it.

But as you are creating icons the best option is to make them as SVG, which will be vector all the way. In some browsers, they will even have a subsampling render.

Comment: Thank you. The only option I have is PNG, and I'm using the asset generation feature as I said, so I'm not sure how sharpening is incorporated here and how I can control it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use smart objects to link to an .ai vector file.  That should keep the clean edge on resize

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Adobe Illustrator. I'm wondering what designers usually do in these cases. I assune such a basic problem should be solvable in Photoshop itself.

Comment: @Hejaziso your saying your only renting photoshop? I mean anything more and you get all adobe apps for free.

Comment: You can technically draw vector objects in Photoshop, but it's a bit tedious.  There's also Inkscape, which a lot of people use, that is freeware that works similar to Illustrator.  You could export or save from there as an EPS, and it should have the same effect.